# using split on a string with separators in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to exrtact a command and arguments *(Node.js)* from users input, for example a user can write one of this cases :

> g!p first video is good
>
> g! play latest game was bad
>
> g!play latest game was bad

in the 1st case : command = "p" and Args="first video is good .... to the end of the string"

in the 2nd case : command = "play" and Args="latest game was .... to the end of the string"

...

```
const command = message.toLowerCase().split("!", 2).join("");
const Args = message.content.split(" ")[2];

if(command === 'play' or command === 'p'){........}
```

i tryed the split function with "!" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match a `!`, followed by zero or more space characters, then match *and capture* the next word (non-space characters), then use a different group to match and capture everything else:

```js
const extract = (str) => {
  const match = str.match(/!\s*(\S+)\s+(.+)/);
  if (!match) {
    return 'No match';
  }
  const [, command, args] = match;
  console.log("Command:" + command, "Args:" + args);
};
extract('g!p first video is good');
extract('g! play latest game was bad');
extract('g!play latest game was bad');
```

Comment: we can also input just a command like : "g!invit" no need for args, but with that regex its always : 'No match' ??

Comment: Make the part after the command optional then: `(?:\s+(.+))?` so that it's in an optional non-capturing group